# is this a safe/good way to implement login with ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, authentication

Hi I have created the code below to check if a user is valid to login to a database, I am using SSL to secure the connection, but I dont know if this is still a good way in which I have done it. Could anyone give advice? Thanks.

(sorry its abit long)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login_styles.css" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/ui/effects.shake.js"></script>

<title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" >
var clicked = 0;

$(document).ready(function() 
{   
    document.form.username.focus();
})
   function make_request()
{
   try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
    {
       httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
    try
    {
        httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return false;   }
    }
    }
}

function checkCanSubmit()
{
    if (fnameok && lnameok && emailok && projectnameok && descriptionok)
    {
    document.getElementById("button").disabled= false;

    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("button").disabled= true;
    }

}

function counting()
 {
clicked++;
 }

function check_login(username, password)
{


make_request()
$("#login_loading").show();
var parameters = 'username=' + document.getElementById("username").value + '&password=' + document.getElementById("password").value;
httpxml.onreadystatechange = stateck;       
httpxml.open('POST', 'login.php', true);
httpxml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpxml.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', parameters.length);
httpxml.send(parameters);

function stateck() 
{

if(httpxml.readyState==4)

    { 
    if (httpxml.responseText.indexOf("Login Successful") >= 0)
    {
    $("#login_loading").hide("fast");
    $("#login_error").hide("slow"); 
    $("#forgot").hide("slow");
    $("#button").fadeOut("slow");       
    $("#loading_big").fadeIn("slow");
    setTimeout( "window.location.href = '../members'", 2000);   


    }
    else
    {
        focus();
        if (clicked > 1)
        {
        $("#login_error").effect("shake", { times:2 }, 100);
        $("#login_loading").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#forgot").show("slow");

        }
        else
        {           
        $("#login_loading").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#login_successful").hide("normal");
        $("#login_error").show("slow");
        }

    }           

    }
}   
}

function focus()
{       
    document.form.username.focus();
}

</script>


   <div class="login_loading" id="login_loading"><img src="images/login_loader.gif"       alt="loading1" id="loading1" /></div>
    <div class="loading_big" id="loading_big">   Login successful please   wait . . .<br /><img src="images/loading_big.gif" alt="loading" /></div>
    <div class="form">
   <table class="form" id="form" cellpadding="10" >
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="login.php" />
   <tr>

    <td>Username</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="26" /></td>

   </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Password</td>
         <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="26"/>

        <div id="login_error" class="login_error" ><img src="images/error.png" alt="Error" id="error" />Username or password incorrect.</div>
        <div id="forgot" class="login_error">Forgot Password?<a   href="forgotpass.php"></a></div>
         <div id="login_successful" class="login_successful" >Login successful please wait . . . </div></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="check_login(username, password); counting(); return false;"/>
</td>
 </tr>
 </form>
 </table>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Code formatting goes abit of a mess on here :p

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from some obvious cleanup points, and the fact that since you're importing jQuery anyway you might as well use its Ajax methods rather than hand-coding your own, I see nothing terribly wrong here. With one huge caveat - `"members"` had better validate that the user has a legitimate login session. What happens if the user accesses `../members` without coming to this login page first, or following a failed login? Are they redirected to the login page?

Comment: Hi, yes I have the full php login system working I just wanted to add an ajax front end. Each page in members is checked for valid sessions etc